# Adding multiple Y axis in Winform Chart C#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I found a couple of posts like this one:
[How to add more Y-axes to MSChart with different scale at left or right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861842/how-to-add-more-y-axes-to-mschart-with-different-scale-at-left-or-right-side)

Explaining how to make a multi-axis graph for Winforms Charts. However, when I try to replicate it, I get the following: [image]

As you can see, the first series has a Y axis (scaled), and the second and third series (third is just under the first) are scaled (since I know the values, which range between 0 and 20). However, as you can see in the image, the axis of the second and thrid series are not drawn. I used the following code from the link above to make the Y-axis.

```
public void CreateYAxis(Chart chart, ChartArea area, Series series, float axisOffset, float labelsSize)
        {
            // Create new chart area for original series
            ChartArea areaSeries = chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea_" + series.Name);
            areaSeries.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            areaSeries.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
            areaSeries.Position.FromRectangleF(area.Position.ToRectangleF());
            areaSeries.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(area.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());
            areaSeries.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            areaSeries.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
            areaSeries.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            areaSeries.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            areaSeries.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
            areaSeries.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            areaSeries.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;


            series.ChartArea = areaSeries.Name;

            // Create new chart area for axis
            ChartArea areaAxis = chart.ChartAreas.Add("AxisY_" + series.ChartArea);
            areaAxis.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            areaAxis.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
            areaAxis.Position.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].Position.ToRectangleF());
            areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());

            // Create a copy of specified series
            Series seriesCopy = chart.Series.Add(series.Name + "_Copy");
            seriesCopy.ChartType = series.ChartType;
            foreach (DataPoint point in series.Points)
            {
                seriesCopy.Points.AddXY(point.XValue, point.YValues[0]);
            }

            // Hide copied series
            seriesCopy.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
            seriesCopy.Color = Color.Transparent;
            seriesCopy.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
            seriesCopy.ChartArea = areaAxis.Name;

            // Disable drid lines & tickmarks
            areaAxis.AxisX.LineWidth = 0;
            areaAxis.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            areaAxis.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
            areaAxis.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            areaAxis.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            areaAxis.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;
            areaAxis.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = area.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font;

            // Adjust area position
            areaAxis.Position.X -= axisOffset;
            areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.X += labelsSize;

        }
```

For the other part of the code, where I create the axis (and there are always 3), I used this:

```
graphPanel.dataGraph.ChartAreas["chartArea"].Position = new ElementPosition(25,10,68,85);
graphPanel.dataGraph.ChartAreas["chartArea"].InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(10,0,90,90);


graphPanel.variableCheckList.Items.Add("Engine Speed", false);
Series series = new Series("Engine Speed");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.Legend = "legend";
graphPanel.dataGraph.Series["Engine Speed"] = series;

graphPanel.variableCheckList.Items.Add("Actual Engine", false);
series = new Series("Actual Engine");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.Legend = "legend";
graphPanel.dataGraph.Series["Actual Engine"] = series;

graphPanel.variableCheckList.Items.Add("Engine Torque", false);
series = new Series("Engine Torque");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.Legend = "legend";
graphPanel.dataGraph.Series["Engine Torque"] = series;

CreateYAxis(graphPanel.dataGraph, graphPanel.dataGraph.ChartAreas["chartArea"], graphPanel.dataGraph.Series["Actual Engine"], 13, 10);
CreateYAxis(graphPanel.dataGraph, graphPanel.dataGraph.ChartAreas["chartArea"], graphPanel.dataGraph.Series["Engine Torque"], 22, 10);
```

Where I create the axis for the 2nd and 3rd series in the bottom two lines.
Does anyone know where this goes wrong? I have been looking and debugging for a while now and still can't figure it out.

Comment: I just went to linked post, i see You are missing alignment part i think they are overlaying each other and that's why they are not visible

Comment: @KubaDo thanks for your answer, where do you see the overlaying part? I don't know where to find that

Comment: instead of reusing same code with "float axisWidth" You have wrote "chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].Position.ToRectangleF()" , and in next lines of You are refirng to Your chart instead of variables, in other words, check You code line by line and do exactly same since they have working example